# How to create an Observer for the OrderCommentSender class

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I need to create an observer of the **vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderCommentSender.php** class, at the **send()** method (83th line), so that I can append a customized comment in the comments section.

Line 83 starts at **$this->eventManager->dispatch**

```
public function send(Order $order, $notify = true, $comment = '') {

$this->identityContainer->setStore($order->getStore());

$transport = [
    'order' => $order,
    'comment' => $comment,
    'billing' => $order->getBillingAddress(),
    'store' => $order->getStore(),
    'formattedShippingAddress' => $this->getFormattedShippingAddress($order),
    'formattedBillingAddress' => $this->getFormattedBillingAddress($order),
    'order_data' => [
        'customer_name' => $order->getCustomerName(),
        'frontend_status_label' => $order->getFrontendStatusLabel()
    ]
];

$transportObject = new DataObject($transport);

/**
 * Event argument `transport` is @deprecated. Use `transportObject` instead.
 */
$this->eventManager->dispatch(
    'email_order_comment_set_template_vars_before',
    ['sender' => $this, 'transport' => $transportObject->getData(), 'transportObject' => $transportObject]
);

$this->templateContainer->setTemplateVars($transportObject->getData());

return $this->checkAndSend($order, $notify); }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you add comment to the $order and in the email, you get it from $order object?

No observer neeed

Comment: Actually I'm not aiming to simply add a comment to the email, but I need to get the comment's content from another table and then automatically add it to the comment section

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try these steps:

Step  1: Choose the event that you would create an observer (access class OrderCommentSender  search eventManager->dispatch, coppy  event name)

Step 2: create events.xml file in folder (ex: //etc/events.xml)

Step 3: insert add observer code in XML file

" instance="\\Observer\ClassNameObserver" />

Step 4: create new ClassNameObserver file following this path: //Observer/ClassNameObserver.php

Step 5: create function execute(Observer $observer)
class ClassNameObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface

```
{
    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        //code implement at here
    }
}
```

Comment: In the doubt that I had, I ended up managing to do it, I just forgot to give the feedback here. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @myname2021 Can you post your solution?